# xorg doesn't detect my AMD Radeon 8600 due "Invalid ATI BIOS from int10, the adapter is not VGA-enabled"

Tags: xorg, ati

I have a Dell Inspiron 15r laptop with Intel CoreI7 4500u and an AMD Radeon 8600 HD and recently I have installed a Debian Jessie Linux with XFCE desktop.
My problem is this: I try to install Fglrx AMD Driver, but when I enable it XServer won't work, the log contains the following message :

```
    [   226.609] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[   226.612] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   226.613] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   226.614] Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt7-1 (2015-03-01) x86_64
[   226.614] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=5aa12b5b-ac46-4da0-8d99-4b981388ce53 ro quiet
[   226.616] Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
[   226.617] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[   226.618] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[   226.620]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   226.620] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   226.624] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr  3 02:41:21 2015
[   226.625] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   226.626] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   226.626] (==) ServerLayout "aticonfig Layout"
[   226.626] (**) |-->Screen "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" (0)
[   226.626] (**) |   |-->Monitor "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
[   226.626] (**) |   |-->Device "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
[   226.626] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   226.626] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   226.626] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   226.627] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   226.627]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   226.627] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[   226.627] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   226.627] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   226.627] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f3350a68d80
[   226.627] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   226.627]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   226.627]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[   226.627]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[   226.627]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[   226.627] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   226.628] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0a16:1028:05ea rev 9, Mem @ 0xc0000000/4194304, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64
[   226.628] (--) PCI: (0:3:0:0) 1002:6660:1028:05ea rev 0, Mem @ 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xc0500000/262144, I/O @ 0x00003000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   226.628] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   226.628] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   226.628] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[   226.628] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[   226.628]    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[   226.628] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[   226.629] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[   226.648] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[   226.648]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.20.7
[   226.648]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   226.649] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[   226.649] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[   226.649] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[   226.649] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[   226.649]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.20.7
[   226.649] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:14.20.7
[   226.649] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-14.201.1006.1002         
[   226.649] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Sep  2 2014 10:14:55
[   226.649] (++) using VT number 1

[   226.649] (--) controlling tty is VT number 1, auto-enabling KeepTty
[   226.649] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[   226.652] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[   226.653] ukiDynamicMajor: failed to open /proc/ati/major
[   226.653] ukiDynamicMajor: failed to open /proc/ati/major
[   226.653] (--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x6660) found
[   226.653] (II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0x7f33527cb380
[   226.653] (II) fglrx(0): === [xdl_xs116_atiddxPreInit] === begin
[   226.654] (**) fglrx(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   226.654] (II) fglrx(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[   226.654] (==) fglrx(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   226.654] (**) fglrx(0): Option "DPMS" "true"
[   226.654] (==) fglrx(0): RGB weight 888
[   226.654] (II) fglrx(0): Using 8 bits per RGB 
[   226.654] (==) fglrx(0): Buffer Tiling is ON
[   226.654] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[   226.654] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[   226.654] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[   226.654] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[   226.654]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.20.7
[   226.654] ukiDynamicMajor: failed to open /proc/ati/major
[   226.654] ukiDynamicMajor: failed to open /proc/ati/major
[   226.654] (**) fglrx(0): NoAccel = NO
[   226.654] (**) fglrx(0): AMD 2D Acceleration Architecture enabled
[   226.654] (--) fglrx(0): Chipset: "EXO XT (6660)" (Chipset = 0x6660)
[   226.654] (--) fglrx(0): (PciSubVendor = 0x1028, PciSubDevice = 0x05ea)
[   226.654] (==) fglrx(0): board vendor info: third party graphics adapter - NOT original AMD
[   226.655] (--) fglrx(0): Linear framebuffer (phys) at 0xa0000000
[   226.655] (--) fglrx(0): MMIO registers at 0xc0500000
[   226.655] (--) fglrx(0): I/O port at 0x00003000
[   226.655] (==) fglrx(0): ROM-BIOS at 0x000c0000
[   226.658] (II) fglrx(0): Invalid ATI BIOS from int10, the adapter is not VGA-enabled
[   226.658] (EE) fglrx(0): Invalid video BIOS signature!
[   226.658] (EE) fglrx(0): GetBIOSParameter failed
[   226.658] (EE) fglrx(0): PreInitAdapter failed
[   226.658] (EE) fglrx(0): PreInit failed
[   226.658] (II) fglrx(0): === [xdl_xs116_atiddxPreInit] === end
[   226.659] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[   226.659] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fglrxdrm"
[   226.659] (II) Unloading fglrxdrm
[   226.659] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fglrxdrm"
[   226.659] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[   226.659] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   226.659] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   226.659] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   226.659] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   226.659] (EE) 
[   226.661] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

So I delete the `xorg.conf` file generated by `aticonfig` tool in order to get to the desktop.

Using `lshw -C Display` I get this:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:64 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c0500000-c053ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0540000-c055ffff
```

Is my problem hardware or software specific ? and is it solvable ?

Comment: Have you tried the AMD drivers from their website? Debian's are going to be out of date.

Comment: Not yet, but as soon as I download I'll give it  a shot, by the way in Debian 8 the driver version is 14.9

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by using `sudo apt-get install fglrx*`.

Then I had 2  new problems:

1. `aticonfig --adapter=all --initial` doesn't detect my Intel HD
   graphics
2. When I boot my computer using AMD, mouse curser becomes invisible (confirmed as a bug in the XServer shipped with Debian testing).

   Also I discovered that AMD switching method between hybrid graphics sucks; instead I added the following line to the generated `xorg.conf` file:

   Section "Device"
       Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
       Driver      "intel"
       BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection

And in the `Screen` section I use the previous identifier to use my Intel HD or identifier `aticonfig-Device[0]-0` to use my AMD like this:

#### Intel HD Graphics:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

#### AMD Graphics

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then I just restart the  Light Display Manager using `sudo service lightdm restart`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution .. dont use binary drivers from AMD but opensource xorg-video-ati with proper amd-ucode, mesa etc.

This pretty old card nicely supported by opensource drivers